# How to disable sslv3 for NSURLconnection or NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, security, nsurlconnection

With respect to the recent security threat with SSLV3,https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/OpenSSL+SSLv3+POODLE+Vulnerability+Official+Release/18827

How can I make NSURLconnection communication secure from this threat?

Can I disable sslv3 programmaticaly in iOS?

Is there any way in iOS by which I can get the supported security protocol list from server url?

Comment: I have tried by setting TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol to kTLSProtocol12 but it is still communicating with sslv3 server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figure out the way to set it into NSURLSession but still struggling with NSURLConnection.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config =
[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
config.TLSMaximumSupportedProtocol = kTLSProtocol12;
config.TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol = kTLSProtocol12  
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig];
```

Comment: [TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol) and the [SSL Protocol Constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SSLProtocol)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you connect try to use kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1 instead of  kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL.

Comment: Is this possible to use this settings with NSURLConnection. Or I need to implement socket APIs for that. Is there any socketconnection library available in iOS which provide GET/POST Request support.